# Cannot always successfully use String.startsWith() when string contains unicode characters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unicode

So I've got a proof-of-concept conjugation practice application I'm building, with Vue.js. One of the key elements is that when you type in an answer to a conjugation, it compares the input text with `String.startswith()`. This is great until the string has unicode characters. It seems that almost always the unicode characters that you input are different than the ones in the database. You can actually visually see in this node CLI example that the version I type in the "ț" character is literally a different character than the one in the database "ţ".

Here is an output of the typed input, it's value and unicode value vs. the comparison:

```
input: anunț // anun\u21B
comparison: anunţ // anun\u163
```

I've tried things like `.normalize()` but it doesn't seem to affect either the inputted string, or the comparison string.

```
> var input = 'anunț'
> var comparison = 'anunţ'
> input === comparison
false
> input.normalize() === comparison
false
> input.normalize() === comparison.normalize()
false
> input === comparison.normalize()
false
/// etc etc with NFC, NFD, NFKC, NFKD forms
> input.normalize()
'anunț'
> comparison.normalize()
'anunţ'

// i've also tried .normalize() with the string decoded into unicode
```

I've tried converting to unicode and **manually** replacing one set of strings, but it only goes so far--- and brings up it's own bunch of issues --- including that sometimes when you type in the answer it will start to have issues doing a positive comparison until the entire string is entered.

Finally I've started to try regex comparisons, but I think this may also be another rabbit hole distraction.

Stripped down to it's most basic logic without any of the above attempts, this is the crux of what I am trying to do, for context:

```
if (this.conjugation.startsWith(this.input)) {
    this.status = "correct";
} else {
    this.status = "incorrect";
}

if (conjugation === val) {
    // okay, we are done
}
```

Any thoughts of how I can get around this? I am currently testing this with Romanian verbs, so the characters appear to be in the following unicode ranges:

`\u0000-\u007F`, `\u0180-\u024F`, `\u0100-\u017F`

Comment: I mean the two *are* actually different characters, why do you expect them to compare as equal? If they *ought* to be the same then that's an error in your data.

Comment: That being said, you *might* be able to use [an `Intl.Collator` with the sensitivity set to `base`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator).

Comment: The strange thing is it seems to be the text input that's off, different character. Every instance I've seen of the example ( ț / ţ ), ţ is used. So I would have to guess possibly a localization issue with macOS :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Intl.Collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator) to construct a collator that only cares about some differences:

```js
var word1 = "anunț"; // anun\u21B
var word2 = "anunţ"; // anun\u163

var collator = new Intl.Collator("ro", { sensitivity: "base" });

console.log(word1 === word2); // the words are not equal
console.log(collator.compare(word1, word2) == 0); // ... but they are "equal enough"
```

Comment: So I suppose then in place of `.startsWith` I could do something like `collator.compare(word1.substring(0, word1.length), word2.substring(0,word1.length)) == 0`

Comment: verified, after about a week of usage, this does indeed work! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

These two characters are very similar, but they are distinct. One has space between the t and the lower comma mark like part of the symbol.

Comment: it is quite possible then that this is a localization issue with macOS. Every example I come across on the web is using the second character, not the input one.